# Excel - Counting cells from the range with multiple criteria (range + wild card)

Tags: excel, wildcard, sumproduct

I have the following table:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Match | Goals scored | Goals lost |
| 2 | Turkey - Italy | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | Turkey - Wales | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | Switzerland - Turkey |  |  |

and I would like to count the number of matches that was won by Turkey.

Lets assume cell Z1 to contain "Turkey" 
and
lets pay attention to the matches where "Turkey" is at the beginning of cells in A ("Turkey - ...")

I considered 2 ways:

1. =SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A4=Z1&" -*"),--(B2:B4>C2:C4))
2. =COUNTIFS(A2:A4,Z1&" -*",B2:B4,">"&C2:C4)

In the first solution, it is not possible to use a range as 4th argument (">"&C2:C4)

However, in the second one, I can not use wildcard ("*"), because it is not allowed in sumproduct function.

How to solve this problem?

I will add that I don't want to write B2+B3+C4, because there is too much data in the whole table (and teams could be changed in the future).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use 2 Columns for the match.